# c- HTTP server on sockets doesn't display image correct

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server

My task is to implement a simple HTTP server. I try to open a site that  I download via HTTP. My server displays html, css and js files properly, but images(png, jpg) don't get displayed. I logged those response packets with Wireshark:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
.PNG
.
```

Also this is my function that read request and send response to client.

```
static int serve_request(int sock, struct conf_arg *arg, char version[])
{
    FILE *html = NULL;
    char buf[MAX_MSG];
    const unsigned chunk = (unsigned)CHUNK_SIZE;
    char *pbuf = NULL;
    char tempbuf[CHUNK_SIZE + 3];
    size_t len;

    strcpy(buf, arg->root);
    if(buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '/')
        strcat(buf, arg->defdoc);
    html = fopen(buf, "rb");
    if (!html) {
        not_found(sock, version);
        return -1;
    }
    good_responce(sock, version);
    do {
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), html) == NULL)
            break;
        pbuf = buf;
        while ((len = strlen(pbuf)) != 0) {
            if (len < chunk) {
                //printf("LEN:%d\n", (int)len);
                sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (int)len);
                write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
                write(sock, pbuf, strlen(pbuf));
                //printf("%s", pbuf);
                pbuf += len;
                write(sock, "\r\n", 2);
            } else {
                sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (int)chunk);
                write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
                //strncpy(tempbuf, pbuf, chunk);
                //printf("%d\n%s\n", (int)chunk, tempbuf);
                write(sock, pbuf, chunk);
                pbuf += chunk;
                write(sock, "\r\n", 2);
            }
        }
    } while (!feof(html));
    strcpy(tempbuf, "0\r\n\r\n");
    write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
    fclose(html);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is, so I hope you can help me.
UPD: I change open mode to rb, but it doesn't help. I get same output in Wireshark.

Comment: You're opening the file in text mode, this *might* be the problem.

Comment: And what mode I should use?

Comment: Binary mode.  That is very likely the problem

Comment: binary, of course?

Comment: I change code and now open file in binary mode, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are those few lines the only content of the packet captured with Wireshark?

Comment: Yes, only this.

Comment: [apart from the open()-mode] You are reading a binary file with fgets(). (also: you seem to like strlen() a lot.) And: you should always use the return values you get from both read() and write().

Comment: Yes, as a general rule, any network code with strlen() in it is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must open the image file in binary mode.

You must use binary file read operations. The buffer you now read does not have an `strlen` because it is binary; the size of the buffer is reported by the `read` operation.

Writing to the socket will also be binary and so `write(sock, pbuf, strlen(pbuf));` will not work, rather use `write(sock, pbuf, n_bytes);` with `n_bytes` the number of bytes from the buffer you want to send.

It could mean re-writing your code to use all binary operations. A css and html file can just as easily be transmitted treating it as binary as treating it as text. If you change your code to all-binary you will not have a problem with any type of file.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite likely that you are not opening the image file in binary mode:

```
 {
   FILE *fp;
   char buffer[512];

   fp = fopen("image_file.png", "rb");
   while...
```

If you do not specify binary mode, you will have weird stuff happen to your binary data.

Additionally, you are using `fgets`, which by its very nature will be incompatible with what you are trying to do with binary data.  You should look into using `fread()`

Comment: Ah...  Updated answer

Comment: In your case I’d expect each element to be one byte. You would attempt to read the number of bytes matching the size of your read buffer.